# How to get the right output on c

Tags: c

These code are running for calculate someone's height and weight to know if he is too fat or not.

But as I run by anything I input, they all output "too fat" does it have any problems.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double height, weight, standardweight;
    int n, i;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d", &height, &weight);
        standardweight = (height - 100) * 0.9;

        if (weight * 0.5 - standardweight >= standardweight * 0.1)
            printf("You are too fat!\n");
        else if (standardweight - weight * 0.5 <= standardweight * 0.1)
            printf("You are too thin!\n");
        else
            printf("You are wan mei!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start by consistently indent your code, and add empty lines to add paragraphs. That will make it easier to read and understand your code.

Comment: The `scanf` should be `scanf("%lf %lf", &height, &weight);` Note that `%d` is for `int` variables. `%lf` is for `double` variables.

Comment: The first condition simplifies to `if (weight >= standard weight * 2.2)` which makes sense. The second condition simplifies to `if (weight >= standardweight * 1.8)`. That should probably be `if (weight <= standardweight * 1.8)`

Comment: This is yet another "wrong specifier used in scanf" FAQ question. `scanf("%d %d",&height,&weight);` is an obvious bug since those are double not int. Decent compilers like gcc will issue a warning even.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are trying to read integers values using the scanf function while you should read double values (%d is for int values).

Change to %lf to read double values:

```
scanf("%lf %lf", &height, &weight);
```

You should also check the scanf return value to see if the function failed (it returns the number of inputs successfully assigned):

```
if(scanf("%lf %lf",&height, &weight) != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "scanf fail!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

It is very strange that your compiler did not warn you about the error, if you missed it pay close attention about the result of your compilation.

I would also suggest to use some printfs when you encounter errors. For example you should have printed the given inputs:

```
printf("height: %lf, weight: %lf\n", height, weight);
```